# Fixing div navigation from hiding upon scroll

Tags: css, html

I have this sample HTML5 page which have a navigation and a content area pasted on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nanojava/bV2LU/1/).

The problem is that `<div id="nav">` isn't fixed when I scroll vertically. How can I make the navigation to be fixed on the top of the browser even with scrolled vertically?

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BG7U8/) what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bV2LU/21/)

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120%;
    background: red;
}
#nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 25px;
    background: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position:fixed` and `z-index` property (the issue you had was due to the layers : your `fixed` `div` was under `#area` div) :

```
#nav{
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   width:100%;
   height: 25px;
   z-index:50;
   background: blue;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/bV2LU/7/)

Comment: It worked well. Unfortunately, `area` should always be under `nav` not behind it. Would it be possible if `z-index` isn't set?

Comment: @Dr. Java: [Like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/bV2LU/20/) Apply `top:25px` to the `#area` div.

Answer (score 0):

Create another hidden navigation (same with already used nav), and show it when user scrolls down enough.

Here is [a good tutorial](http://designshack.net/articles/javascript/simple-steps-for-creating-a-fixed-navigation-bar/) to do that.

And here is [some edited and working example](http://vinekutusu.com/) from my website.